# Shared shopping cart between subsites

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I'm trying to get a fully functionally Magento 1.6.1.0 installation with 3 sub-sites and a main site (configured each as store inside Magento), that share of course the clients information across the all the stores.

The problem is that I can't seems to be able to have a persistent shopping cart across the all stores, allowing the customers to get products from a sub-site then another and so on without having to pay each time the shipping fees for what is at the end only 1 order.

I've followed several different tutorials that claimed to be able to achieve that but none of them worked as expected, and also none of them specified to which version of Magento they where supposed to work.

Any tip is welcome, thanks to everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any working solution